# Image transformation not applied after orientation change with Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I am using Picasso and a [RoundedTransformation class](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView) that applies rounded corners to an image I load with Picasso. Relevant code is below:

```
Transformation transformation = new RoundedTransformationBuilder()
            .cornerRadiusDp(4)
            .oval(false)
            .build();

ImageView cardViewTop1Image = (ImageView) cardViewTop1.findViewById(R.id.cv_top1_image);
Picasso.with(cardViewTop1.getContext()).load("http:/some_image_url.com")
            .fit().centerCrop()
            .transform(transformation).into(cardViewTop1Image);
```

This all works great until I go through two orientation changes - first to horizontal orientation, then back to vertical orientation. When I switch back to vertical orientation, the rounded transformation is no longer applied.

I believe that Picasso is caching the non-transformed image and then filling the ImageView with it. Is there a way I could cache the transformed image or load the non-transformed image from the cache and then apply the transformation? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm also seeing a similar issue. Has a solution to this problem been found yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach to stop caching.

```
Picasso.with(yourContext)
        .load(yourUrl)
        .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE )
        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
        .fit()
        .centerCrop()
        .transform(yourTransformation)
        .into(yourImageView);
```

Or try another Transformation. I use this https://gist.github.com/aprock/6213395 .